# Decorating function beans so that they insert thread local (spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

We are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka and we define our consumers as beans like so:

```java
@Bean
public Consumer<SomeEvent> someEventConsumer() {
  /* logic */
}
```

Is there any way I can define a "decorator" for all bindings in my app. Essentially this decorator will look in the kafka headers and retrieve a value and then attach it as a thread local for the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean and use it to add a `RecordInterceptor` to the binding's listener container.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_consumer_configuration

Comment: Is there any easy way to get it to be added to every consumer binding in the app?

Comment: Yes, by adding a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean - it will be called for each binding.